# Pry not working on Docker container with pure Ruby application (No Rails)

Tags: ruby, docker

Currently I'm working on a pure Ruby application no Rails. When I try to use `pry` with Docker it gets stuck. I have success to get pry to work in Rails but not in a pure ruby application. When `binding.pry` is hit, I then go and run `docker attach 1f8bc4aa4ac6` to attach to the container but still nothing is run.

```
[1] pry(LambdaFunctions::WebhookHandler)> form_fields
```

The dependencies are in the Gemfile, so I don't think I have to get a `pry` image, or do I? Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Start with AWS lambda ruby environment
FROM lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.5

WORKDIR /var/task

# Install MySQL
RUN yum -y install mysql-devel
```

This is `pry` version I'm using in my Gemfile:

```
      gem 'pry', '~> 0.12.2'
```

This is the command I'm using for running the container:

```
 docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/task -e TENANCY="local" -e SUBMISSION_ID="{{submission_id}}" -t online-apps:latest bash scripts/webhook/formstack_webhook.sh
```

Comment: Does adding a `docker run -i` option help?

Comment: what you posted in Gemfile is `rspec` not `pry`

Comment: Fixed it, a copy paste small mistake

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `-it` to the docker command in order for it to work.

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/task -e -it TENANCY="local" -e SUBMISSION_ID="{{submission_id}}" -t online-apps:latest bash scripts/webhook/formstack_webhook.sh
```